# I am attempting to spy field elements in HTML Webpage but after page refreshed the path values are getting changed

Tags: blueprism, rpa

How to handle the attributes that captured in application modular?
Id or Path?

Answer (score 2):

check if parent URL attribute is checked. if check, please uncheck it. and check the path after you spy the element.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, URL was one of my bigest problem.